# Linux equivalent of MS StreamingVideoDownloader

Tags: linux, video, streaming, mms-streaming

is there something on Linux like this : http://www.binarymark.com/Products/StreamingVideoDownloader/default.aspx ?

When we start to play a video file in a browser, the software start to save & capture MMS URL . That's interesting for videos DownloadHelper firefox extension doesn't "see".

Comment: Have you tried installing Firefox and SVD under WINE?

Comment: No, but I would like to understand what's SVD accomplish. If windows can, Linux too ! Is it based on a proxy or such ? SVD in not open source AFAIK.

Comment: [The Mozilla Developer's Mailing List](https://groups.google.com/group/mozilla.dev.extensions/browse_thread/thread/a2ddcf249bfddde5) has some insights on how [Video DownloadHelper](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/video-downloadhelper/) works. It'd be interesting to know what sites VDH chokes on.